# If $A=\begin {bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, find $A^n$ for positive integer $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A=\begin {bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, find $A^n$ for positive integer $n$.

Now my method of solving these were to take $n=1,2,3..$, find the respective value and analyse the options to find the right one. It works well, but I never quite figured out how to do this properly, in case options aren’t given. Thanks!

Comment: For an upper triangular matrix the diagonal terms will always be to the $n$th power. This leaves the only tricky part being figuring out what the off diagonal term will be.

Comment: Note that by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem$$A^{n+2}=(a+1)A^{n+1}-aA^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=1$ then it is straightforward to show that $A^n = \begin{bmatrix}1 & nb \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Suppose $a \neq 1$. Then with $v_1 = e_1, v_2 = (-b, a-1)^T$ we have
$A^n v_1 = a v_1, A^n v_2 = v_2$. Let $V= \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2, \end{bmatrix}$, then

$A = V \begin{bmatrix}a^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} V^{-1} = {1 \over ad}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -b \\ 0 & a-1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a^n & {a^n-1 \over a-1} b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

This formula holds for all $n$, of course.

Comment: I think I am not familiar with the terminology being used here. What is $V, v_1, e_1$

Comment: $e_1 = (1,0)^T$. I have chosen $v_1 = e_1$. $V$ is the matrix whose columns are $v_1, v_2$.

Comment: You could skip all that jazz and just validate inductively.

Comment: Yes, induction was the first method I used, but that won’t be possible if options are not given. Of course, I think I am stepping a bit out of my territory here, maybe I was never meant to solve it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I mean, check my formula for $n=0$ (or $n=1$ depending on where you like to start) and then check that it holds inductively.

Comment: No your formula works, that’s not the problem.

Comment: This formula comes from diagonalization matrix. It works well.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The characteristic equation is $$(\lambda-1)(\lambda-a)=0\to \lambda^2=
(a+1)\lambda+a$$Based on Cayley-Hamilton's theorem
$$A^2=(a+1)A+a$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you're interesting.

$A=B+C$ where $B=\begin {bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $C=\begin {bmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

We have $B^n=\begin {bmatrix} a^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $C^2=0$ and $BC=aCB=\begin {bmatrix} 0 & ab \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

So $A^n=(B+C)^n=B^n+\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}B^i C B^{n-1-i}$

We have $B^i C B^{n-1-i}=aB^{i-1}C B^{n-i}=\cdots=a^iCB^{n-1}=a^i \begin {bmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $ so

$$A^n=B^n+\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^i C B^{n-1}=\begin {bmatrix} a^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}+\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^i \begin {bmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix} a^n & b\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^i \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
If $a=1$ then $A^n=\begin {bmatrix} 1 & nb \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

If $a\neq 1$ then $A^n=\begin {bmatrix} a^n & b\frac{a^n-1}{a-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks a lot I see my mistake.